GetFloat returns different value for number more than 7 decimal digits
We are using getfloat() to fetch the record. But when we saved the data in the table value stored was different from the original value.
Float givenFloat = new Float(16797533);
String result = String.format("%f", givenFloat);
System.out.println(result);

Result is 16797532.000000
I want to know why getFloat() is behaving like this.
I have changed the getFloat() to getString() to retreive data.

You have a type conversion going on that is causing you to lose some precision. Why are you using Float at all in this case?

check the result and documentation of Math.ulp(16797533f) - also try What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic and What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, ...
